# Issues when generating NUXT build

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I am building a nuxt ssr app and whenever I run build command, I get this error of css-loader related to Invalid options object.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/components/streetViewPanorama.vue (./node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?minimize!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"optionsId":"0","vue":true,"scoped":false,"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/components/streetViewPanorama.vue)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, icss?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, esModule? }
    at validate (D:\Dev\Vuejs\Nuxt\nuxt-app\node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\css-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:98:11)       
    at Object.loader (D:\Dev\Vuejs\Nuxt\nuxt-app\node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
 @ ./node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/components/streetViewPanorama.vue (./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?minimize!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"optionsId":"0","vue":true,"scoped":false,"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/components/streetViewPanorama.vue) 4:14-295
 @ ./node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/components/streetViewPanorama.vue
 @ ./node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/main.js
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./components/GoogleMap.vue
 @ ./components/GoogleMap.vue
 @ ./components/AddPost.vue
 @ ./components/Header.vue
 @ ./layouts/nossr.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
```

I have install the css-loader as well but the issue persists. Below is my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "deploy": "push-dir --dir=dist --branch=gh-pages --cleanup",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "12.6.0",
    "@capacitor-community/http": "1.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "2.4.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.6",
    "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "1.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "0.1.10",
    "@mathieustan/vue-datepicker": "^0.2.11",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/svg": "^0.4.0",
    "@vue-stripe/vue-stripe": "4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.4",
    "capacitor-resources": "2.0.5",
    "cordova-res": "0.15.3",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "cropperjs": "1.5.9",
    "crypto-js": "4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "5.0.0",
    "debounce": "1.2.0",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "2.1.2",
    "jquery": "1.9.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "lru-cache": "6.0.0",
    "luxon": "1.25.0",
    "masonry-layout": "4.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.9.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "number-abbreviate": "^2.0.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
    "photoswipe": "^5.2.4",
    "postcss": "8.1.10",
    "postcss-import": "13.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-url": "10.1.1",
    "push-dir": "^0.4.1",
    "rxjs": "6.6.3",
    "simple-vue-validator": "0.16.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "underscore": "^1.13.1",
    "v-datatable-light": "0.8.2",
    "v-lazy-image": "1.4.0",
    "video-metadata-thumbnails": "1.0.22",
    "vue-datatables-net": "1.4.1",
    "vue-datetime": "1.0.0-beta.13",
    "vue-loader": "14.2.4",
    "vue-meta": "2.4.0",
    "vue-quill-editor": "3.0.6",
    "vue-router": "3.3.4",
    "vue-rx": "6.2.0",
    "vue-scroll": "^2.1.13",
    "vue-select": "^3.10.3",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "vue-tables-2": "^2.3.1",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vue-tippy": "^4.7.2",
    "vue-toast-notification": "0.4.1",
    "vue2-datepicker": "3.8.2",
    "vue2-google-maps": "0.10.7",
    "vue2-timepicker": "^1.1.6",
    "vuejs-clipper": "3.0.3",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "1.6.2",
    "vuetable-2": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "vuex": "3.4.0",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "3.0.1",
    "weekstart": "1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "eslint": "6.7.2",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "sass": "^1.50.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-masonry-css": "1.0.3"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I have searched alot but couldn't find any solution. kindly help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did quite a leap of 0.x into 5.0 regarding the `css-loader` here. You should use what is recommended in this breaking change: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Comment: You want me to downgrade to 1.0.0?

Comment: No, I meant that you missed the breaking change at 1.0.0. So a super old update as you can see, since you're using 5.0.0

Comment: I dont understand how this is the solution? Can you just let me know how to fix it?

Comment: You're using the v5 version but your error is showing that your API is not up to date. There was a breaking change at v1 (probably in v2, v3 etc... too), so as stated in the given link you should `remove minimize option, use postcss-loader with cssnano or use optimize-cssnano-plugin plugin` in order to fix the initial issue.

Comment: How to use postcss-loader with ccssnano? Can you be more specific? What minimize option to remove?

Comment: First thing would be to write down your current Webpack configuration for us to see what's inside. Because you should have a `minimize` key there, that is not supported anymore (as you can read in your error). Then, reading my link would be nice because everything is given there.

Comment: I am using nuxt. I havent configured webpack myself its done by nuxt.

Comment: Please share any relevant configuration/code that may be useful to solve this bug.

Comment: There is no other code that's causing this issue expect the packages installed. The best I can do is add nuxt.config.js. I have been searching for this issue since 3 days now, and couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Heh, there is quite a big project here tbh. So there is probably an error somewhere with all the code next to it. Is the Github repo public?

Comment: This project cant be made public. But I can create a dummy project with the issue. Will that help?

Comment: Yep, a [repro] is always welcome.

Comment: Here you go
https://github.com/ahmedkhan1/cssloader

Comment: @kissu did you check?

Comment: You didn't gave me the value of `API_URL`. Also, the repro is having the issue but I'm not sure what even `css-loader` is used for. I mean, you're having a lot of packages. What even is `@nuxt/webpack` used for? Some cleanup may be mandatory to start, on top of checking what could be upgraded across all your NPM packages. `@nuxtjs/dotenv` is not useful anymore. I'm pretty sure you could upgrade + remove some stuff and having it working just fine. Also check what you're doing with your CSS, using `stylus` need some specific configuration. Remove deprecated stuff like Moment.js + jQuery etc...

Comment: At the end, you need somebody who knows the Vue ecosystem + your app to do some proper cleanup to solve all of this. It's important to stay up to date and to keep track of your project to not fall behind. Using specific or deprecated things may also need some very special care, because they can be poorly supported (or just not at all). TLDR: I can't help you via a simple comment section and a few files mimicking the issue. Maybe start a brand new Nuxt project, dump the files from your [repro] and make it work there. Then slowly migrate into your actual production private project.

Comment: @kissu Most of the libs are being used and so is the API_URL. But I just gave you a dummy project with the expected issue.

Comment: A dummy project with your whole full list of exact dependencies will not solve the issue, because they are out of date.

Comment: You dont need to worry about the resource not being as this is just a dummy project so the resources are all being used in the real project.

Comment: So what do you recommend?

Comment: I can create a totally working project with the given files minus all your fancy dependencies. What is not working, are the dependencies themselves not the few JS files. So, solving the issue requires the actual context, not a dummy setup. As what I recommend, it's already written few comment above.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I will follow your approach.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not really solvable without having the whole context and making an in-depth analysis of all the packages one by one: upgrading the legacy ones, removing the deprecated ones and figuring out what kind of specific configuration is in place (Stylus for example).

The given reproduction kinda shows the issue, but we cannot just solve them in `package.json` because it may break the logic that is based on those specific versions.

Since the project is private, there is no real way to help here without having more info.